# How to keep seeing the data from the start when the data keeps coming in LIghtningChartJS?

Tags: javascript, charts, dashboard, lightningchart, lineseries

I went through one of your interactive examples, Dashboard 5 channels 1000 pps chart. In that as the data keeps coming, the view area starts scrolling so that I can see the new coming data. But in this process the data at the start goes out of view... What I want is, I want to see the new data as well as I want to see all the data from the start in view all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the [AxisScrollStrategy](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.0/classes/axis.html#setscrollstrategy) to [`AxisScrollStrategies.fitting`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.0/globals.html#axisscrollstrategies.fitting) or [`AxisScrollStrategies.expansion`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.0/globals.html#axisscrollstrategies.expansion)

```js
series.axisX.setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.expansion)
```